# AWS return custom api error message when IAM policy denies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

we have a policy we are attaching to roles that's ensuring the ec2 provisioner has included the required tags defined by our finance department. [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121514/ec2-iam-policy-to-require-tags/43127758)

I can picture an engineer getting frustrated when each time he tries to spin up an EC2 instance it's immediately shut down because he forgot to include required tags and hit a DENY in the iam policy, but he has no way of knowing.

I was hoping for a custom error description return by the api.  It doesn't have to be iam, if there's a benefit to instead use lambda fired off the cloudwatch runinstances event, I'm open to that as well.

**What can we do to inform the engineer his instance was shutdown due to missing required tags?**

Would love to hear your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS offers a base set of APIs. It's impossible to provide every feature that all users want, but using the base APIs anyone can build a service *on top of* AWS.

For example, instead of having your developers launch instances directly through AWS, you could have them use a custom interface (perhaps a page on an Intranet) where they can request certain services. This interface can then call AWS APIs on their behalf, **including required elements, such as tags**. It's like storage -- people don't write directly to the disk, they do it through their operating system.

If that's too low-level for you, an alternative is to use **AWS CloudFormation**, which launches services based upon a template. The template can collect the required information or automatically add it to instances when they are launched.

Then, throw in **AWS Service Catalog** and you can *force* users to launch services through CloudFormation templates. Service Catalog offers a list of services (effectively just CloudFormation templates) that users can launch -- **even if the users don't have permission to launch the services themselves!**

For example, let's say your developers do not have permission to create a an Amazon EC2 instance. You could provide a template via Service Catalog that launches an EC2 instance on their behalf but also enforces your standards, such as tagging, subnets, security groups, etc.

**Bottom line:** If you don't see something in AWS that specifically meets your needs, you can often build it on top of AWS either via your own code or via AWS Service Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr The access denied message does include the condition it failed on.

The [sample linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121514/ec2-iam-policy-to-require-tags/43127758) to provides an IAM policy to deny RunInstances if tags were not also included in the RunInstances api call. Resource level permissions were [provided in March of 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/) allowing users to include tags in the RunInstances api call as well as allowing IAM to enforce ec2 resource level permissions, in this case, enforcing users to include required tags.

Prior to March 2017, two api calls were required to create tags:

1. `ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-6df1e514 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --subnet-id subnet-e25e29bb`
2. `ec2-create-tags <instanceid> --tag "Name=<value>" --tag "App=<value>" --tag "AppOwner=<value>" --tag "Environment=<value>"`

*After implementing this iam policy the workflow above would DENY on step 1.*

Here’s the new workflow for provisioning an EC2 instance which includes tags:

1. `ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-6df1e514 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --subnet-id subnet-e25e29bb --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=name,Value=required_tag_name_value},{Key=App,Value=required_tag_app_value},{Key=AppOwner,Value=required_tag_appowner_value},{Key=Environment,Value=required_tag_env_value}]'`

Based on the sample iam policy linked to, if the user does not include the required tags, the returned error message is encoded and is displayed to the user as such:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the
>   RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this
>   operation. Encoded authorization failure message:
>   zGetZzIIedikZSAbE4YGEGhy1ytjrXD8Ak-hr1UJvDkKW7wzDu27ZS0NfMGaOUBQGO1I3b3v6Us8BXO-41973SckcmEH17019Sheua16dmrTPYHYymw9pftYope_jmR6MgsvH1bMP0FE_gHnEvaJCIMNukOo-utK....

If the user's iam policy also includes the sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage, they can decode the message with the following:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <encoded message here>
```

> {
>       "DecodedMessage": "{\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":true,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[{\"statementId\":\"\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAJVNFHTEF6I2STOU\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/AppOwner\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}}]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"AROAJVNFHTEF6I2STOU-CLI-session-1501883988\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/_test_require_tags/AWS-CLI-session-1501883988\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::instance/*\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"ec2:Tenancy\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"default\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:AvailabilityZone\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-west-2c\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-west-2\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:ebsOptimized\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"t2.micro\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:RootDeviceType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ebs\"}]}}]}}}"
>   }

While a little difficult to read, we can see which condition the RunInstance calls failed on:

> aws:RequestTag/AppOwner\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}}]},\"failures\":