# Attach iam policy to every role that RunInstances

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, boto3

I have an [iam policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121514/ec2-iam-policy-to-require-tags/43127758) that requires Runinstances to also include four tags our Finance department has deemed required.

I'd like to attach this policy to all roles, however, we can not make use of AWS Orgs.

What are some ways I can achieve this?  Some ideas I have thought of are

- Cloudwatch event monitoring for RunInstances event, then determining
  which role was used and attaching my iam policy to it. (subsequent RunInstances calls will be denied if no tags included)
- Using boto (scheduled) to iterate through all roles in the account and attach my iam policy.

What's a good way of achieving my objective to deploy my iam policy so RunInstances events include the required tags?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to enforce tags:

- Enforce them when instances are launched, or
- Check instances on a regular basis, [identifying instances that violate a tagging policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-config-checking-for-compliance-with-new-managed-rule-options/)

AWS Organizations cannot provide this level of fine-grained control -- it can only grant or deny specific API calls (eg `ec2:RunInstance`) without any conditions.

To enforce tags upon launch, you would need to modify all policies that grant RunInstances permission. Alternatively, you could create a Deny policy and attach it to all users, which would override the standard Allow policy. See: [EC2 IAM policy to require tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186405/174777)

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I'm trying to deploy the later solution "create a Deny policy and attach it to all users". I'm asking what are some methods of deploying this solution, taking into account changes to the environment like new users (in this case)