# Enforce tag policy for all services in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need a AWS IAM policy to enforce Tagging for all the services. (Not One By One). 
Is that possible?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyCreateSecretWithNoProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Project": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyRunInstanceWithNoProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Project": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyCreateSecretWithNoCostCenterTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/CostCenter": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyRunInstanceWithNoCostCenterTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/CostCenter": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is from AWS Documentation. I need all aws services together.

Comment: Your example policy is SCP for AWS Organizations. If your account is not in AWS org, you can't use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637920/enforcing-tagging-for-resources-in-aws

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enforce tagging for all possible resources up front. I recommend reading AWS white paper:

- [Tagging Best Practices - Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-tagging-best-practices.pdf)

Even with AWS Organization and TagPolicies you can't fully enforce tags [since](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_tag-policies-enforcement.html):

> Enforcement has no effect on resources that are created without tags.

Also with AWS Organization's TagPolicies only [some resources are supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_supported-resources-enforcement.html), not all resources available in AWS.

The white paper recommends using CloudFormation and Service Catalog to **proactively tag resources**.

Answer (score 0):

If the account is part of an Organisation it can be enforced through tagging policies: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_tag-policies.html.

If not you can use the AWS config rule of required tags: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible.

first you cannot use "*" for resources. e.g EC2 creates EBS volumes, ENIs ... and some cannot be tagged so you won't be able to spin up an instance

second not all AWS services creates the tags during resource creation. e.g S3 won't send the tags while for the createBucket request

third some AWS services uses requestTag some use awsTags during resource creation.

So, you need to go service by service and test those services one by one :( then you will hit SCP size limit (5120 byte)....